# What compiles .cl files when calling clBuildProgram() API?

Tags: opencl

I wonder what kind of compiler compiles .cl files when we call `clBuildProgram()` API during the runtime? Is that depends on the device?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a program from source and call `clBuildProgram()`, OpenCL runtime performs on-line compilation of the source. Each OpenCL runtime from the vendor includes OpenCL C compiler. Usually, the compiler is implemented as a shared library and supports only certain type of devices. For example, [Intel OpenCL runtime for GPU](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime) uses [Intel Graphics Compiler](https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler) library to compile the source for Intel GPU devices.